# How to get related model_set on querying with filter

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Let's say I have 2 models

```
class Shipment(models.Model):
    # ...

class ShipmentTimeline(models.Model):
    shipment = models.ForeignKey(
        Shipment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="shipmenttimeline")
```

I want to get related `ShipmentTimeline` objects along with the Shipment filtered list in one go. For Now, I'm querying the shipments like:

```
Shipment.objects.filter(
            # some filters
        ).only('id')
```

As here I have IDs and then if I go with `get()` query first and then related_set of each shipment and then appending to a new list. it would be a lot of mess I guess in the for loops. Any better way to get the data like

```
qs = [{'Shipment 1', ['ShipmentTimeline_x', 'ShipmentTimeline_y']}, ...]
```

Comment: `Shipment.objects.filter(...).prefetch_related('shipmenttimeline_set')`?

Comment: Yes , I have tried that, And `AttributeError: Cannot find 'shipmenttimeline_set' on Shipment object, 'shipmenttimeline_set' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()`

Comment: Did you specify a `related_name` for your `ForeignKey`?

Comment: Yes , its `shipmenttimeline`

Comment: @atropebelladona: then it is `.prefetch_related('shipmenttimeline')`.